# Capture Screenshot Windows Forms by c#

Tags: c#, forms, screenshot, capture, snapshot

I have some form in one project (application) and in the main form have one button (Capture Button) 
when I click in capture button my program capture Screenshot all another forms

other forms maybe minimize or not show yet ! or behind Main forms

I use this code

```
Form1 theForm = new Form1();                           
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(theForm.Width, theForm.Height))
{
       theForm.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
       bitmap.Save(@"c:\TEST.bmp");
}
```

it work fine but don't show Forms Control in the captured image

How can i captured some forms when forms not showed or minimize or behind another form ?

Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your problem !!! `but don't show Forms Control in the captured image`

Comment: captured screenshot just empty forms without any control into form

Comment: I have given you a solution please try it and let me know if it is working for you !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
 using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
 {
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
       g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save("c://My_Img.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20651/Capturing-Minimized-Window-A-Kid-s-Trick

if i'm understanding you correctly, you want to take screenshots of all open application, minimized, maximized, topmost and non topmost.

the article basically describes how to get all handles of all open windows, maximize -> screenshot -> minimize.

you could use this to just set all application to not be minimized, take note of which were minimized and then minimize these after the screenshot has been taken.